# unexpected EOF exception using rumtimeexec

Tags: java, shell, runtime, exec

```
String cmdStr = "/bin/sh -c \"if [ -h /tmp/swwc12 ] ; 
then echo exists; fi\""; 
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(getCmdArr(cmdStr)); 


public static final String[] getCmdArr(String cmdStr) 
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(cmdStr);
    String[] cmdArr = new String[st.countTokens()];
    for (int i=0; st.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
      cmdArr[i] = st.nextToken();
    }
    return ( cmdArr );
}
```

expected output to show if symlink exist or not for given path.

actual result :
command is /bin/sh -c "if [ -h /tmp/swwc12 ] ; then echo exists; fi"

output:

error

[: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
[: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: why are you not writing `if` statement in one line ? like `String cmdStr = "/bin/sh -c \"if [ -h /tmp/swwc12 ] ; then echo exists; fi\"";`

Comment: yes in one line only. stack overflow formatting , it came on second line.